# How do I tell MariaDB to differ between characters with and without accents in primary key?

Tags: mariadb

We have a MySQL table with `utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci` and want it to merge to MariaDB for performance reasons (and because in our new infrastructure we only use MariaDB). Unfortunately, MariaDB does not support that collation. The newer alternative is `_520_` but it does not support accents (sensitive or insensitive).

How can I have accents as primary keys that differ from chars without an accent? I cannot find anything related to accents for MariaDB, but a lot for MySQL. Tho I thought MariaDB wanted to be a replacement for MySQL or at least as close as possible but they both differ a lot in case of collations.

What are the alternatives?

*We run MariaDB 10.9*

Here is an example SQL of the problem:

```sql
SET NAMES utf8mb4 ;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `synonyms`;
SET character_set_client = utf8mb4 ;
CREATE TABLE `synonyms` (
  `synonym` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`synonym`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci;
LOCK TABLES `synonyms` WRITE;
INSERT INTO `synonyms` VALUES ('Montenegro'),('Monténégro');
UNLOCK TABLES;
```

Comment: Here is an answer from the MariaDB forum, which says that Unicode v14 is coming in MariaDB 10.10 with support for `ai`, `as`, `ci` and `cs`. https://mariadb.com/kb/en/how-do-i-set-accent-insensitivity/

Comment: Which do you get on MariaDB 10.9?  2 rows to be inserted?  Or "Duplicate key" error message?  Do you care what happens to "montenegro" (case differs)?

Comment: Hey @RickJames, with the above SQL we get "Duplikate key", yes. In that case, case sensitivity isn't our issues, just accent sensitivity. So lowercased montenegro should match Montenegro but not the lower cased monténégro.

Comment: You want `_as_ci`.  Alas, only available in 8.0 or 10.10.

Answer (score 1):

Before the advent of MySQL 8.0's `_ai_ci` (etc) collations, look for `COLLATIONs` ending with _ci`-- it meant both accent-insensitive and case-insensitive.  And the opposite case is any`COLLATION`ending`_bin`, meaning to simply compare the bits, that is, accent and case 'sensitive'.

To find the collations available for, say, the `CHARACTER SET` "utf8mb4", do

```
SHOW COLLATION LIKE 'utf8mb4%';
```

Here is a rundown of _ci collations that *may* match the particular version of 10.x you are using:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/utf8_collations.html  It's goal is to point out the occasional differences among `utf8` collations.

**Monténégro**

```
mysql> SELECT 'Montenegro' = 'Monténégro' COLLATE utf8mb4_bin;
+---------------------------------------------------+
| 'Montenegro' = 'Monténégro' COLLATE utf8mb4_bin   |
+---------------------------------------------------+
|                                                 0 | (means false)
+---------------------------------------------------+

+--------------------------------------------------------------+
| 'Montenegro' = 'Monténégro' COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci   |
+--------------------------------------------------------------+
|                                                            1 |
+--------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Those two words (without and with accents) compare unequal for a *bin* collation but equal for most other collations.

MariaDB and MySQL don't have the same set of collations for utf8mb4; here are the rules:

```
_bin -- ignore accents and capitalization, so 'Montenegro' != 'Monténégro'
_as_ versus _ai_ -- accent sensitive versus insensitive
_ci (without _as_ or _ai_) -- accent insensitive
```

When 'Montenegro' = 'Monténégro', you get "Duplicate key".

(Don't use the Collate clause like I did; instead declare the column to have the desired collation.)

Comment: I still get "Duplicate entry 'Monténégro' for key 'PRIMARY'" I will post a sample SQL in my question.

Comment: In the link I can only find MySQL collations, but I want to migrate to MariaDB which does not have them. As state before I tested with any _ci collation without success. Just binary did work but.

Comment: Both MySQL and MariaDB have the `CHARACTER SET utf8mb4` -- That controls the _encoding_.  `COLLATION` controls comparison (case folding, etc.).

Comment: Ofc.. but none of the MariaDB collations ending with _ci works as expected. Try my SQL above.

Comment: @muuvmuuv - Do you want them to be treated as equal?  See what I added.  Your table definition should get "Duplicate Key".

Comment: No, I thought my headline was clear... sorry. Both should be treated differently. Thanks for the added parts. Its more clear now for me. Sad that only binary comparison works. I have seen MariaDB is working on Unicode 14 support with 10.10 release. I will test _bin but I remeber having other issues with it when I tested it.

Comment: "_ci (without _as_ or _ai_) -- accent insensitive" – this is only true for MySQL, in MariaDB its sensitive as from your test and also mine.

Comment: @muuvmuuv - Hmmm...  That sounds like a serious incompatibility between the products.

Comment: Yes, that is the point. Maybe we have an edge case which no one had before (cannot believe it actually) but Primary keys and Accent + Case insensitivity is a mandatory feature for a database...